# Is there any relationship between quadratic residues in $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ and even permutations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I have just learned about quadratic residues and nonresidues, and there are two properties concerning them in $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$:

1. There are as many residues as nonresidues $\mod p$.
2. The product of two residues is a residue, the product of two
   nonresidues is a residue, and the product of a residue and a nonresidue is a
   nonresidue.

I notice them quite similar to the properties of even and odd permutations in a permutation group. Specifically, if a permutation group $G$ contains an odd permutation, then:

1. There are as many even permutations as odd ones in $G$.
2. The product of two even permutations is again an even one, the product of two
   odd permutations is an even permutation, and the product of an even permutation and an odd permutation is an odd permutation.

I wonder if it is possible to construct a faithful permutation representation of  $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, which takes the subgroup of residues to the normal subgroup of even permutations, and takes nonresidues to odd ones? If so, are there any applications of this representation (could it even be used to prove the quadratic reciprocity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common setting for both situation is the following: $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of index $2$ (here, either the subgroup of quadratic residues, or of even permutations).

In that case, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ (this is not special when $G$ is abelian, but for the symmetric group it is significant), so there is a group morphism $G\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with kernel $H$ (when $G$ is the symmetric group, this morphism is the signature of permutations).

There are only two classes modulo $H$: the elements in $H$, and those not in $H$. As always, all the classes have the same cardinality, so there are as many elements in $H$ as not in $H$.

The fact that $G/H\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ gives you the multiplication rule that you described: you can say that elements in $H$ are "even" and those not in $H$ are "odd", and then you have the usual even/odd rule.

There is no special deeper link between the two situations, but this setting of having a subgroup of order $2$ is very common and important in mathematics. You can see that developping abstract algebraic concepts allows us to understand the connexion between seemingly different situations.